# Configuring DSVL to show camera images from Logitech9000 webcam

Tags: video, camera, directshow, webcam

I am trying to view camera feed from a Logitech9000 camera using DSVL(DirectShow Video Library) http://sourceforge.net/projects/dsvideolib/. The xml file currently looks as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dsvl_input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Documents and Settings\Thomas\My Documents\projects\ARToolKit &amp; DSVideoLib\ARVideoLib\DsVideoLib\DsVideoLib.xsd">
        <camera show_format_dialog="false" friendly_name="Logitech Webcam Pro 9000">
                <pixel_format>
                        <RGB24 flip_v="false"/>
                </pixel_format>
        </camera>
</dsvl_input>
```

However, the image that comes up looks vertically inverted. I tried changing the flip_v value to true in the config above but it did not make any difference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After I watch through DSVideoLib.xsd, RGB24 does not have flip_v/flip_h options, only RGB32 has. Try to get your input as RGB32, could work, depends on your webcam driver.

Answer (score 0):

The webcam had an option of inverting the video in its Advanced Settings so that resulted in a upright picture in the end.